# How to pass header information to a custom Jackson JSON deserializer

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jackson

I have a custom Jackson JSON deserializer that converts a user's local timestamp to UTC:

Jackson Config:

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public Module javaTimeModule() {
        JavaTimeModule module = new JavaTimeModule();
        module.addDeserializer(LocalDateTime.class, new JsonDatetimeDeserializer());
        module.addSerializer(LocalDateTime.class, new JsonDatetimeSerializer());

        return module;
    }
}
```

Deserializer:

```
public class JsonDatetimeDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<LocalDateTime> {

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext)
            throws IOException {

        String timestamp = jsonParser.getText();
        DateTimeFormatConstant dateTimeFormat = findDateTimeFormat(timestamp);
        LocalDateTime deserializedTime = null;

        if (dateTimeFormat != null) {
            switch (dateTimeFormat) {
                case ISO -> deserializedTime = localTimeToUtc(timestamp, dateTimeFormat.value());
                case ISO_WITH_OFFSET -> deserializedTime = zonedTimeWithOffsetToUtc(timestamp, dateTimeFormat.value());
                //Add more cases here as more formats are supported and added to DateTimeFormatConstant
            }
        }
        return deserializedTime;
    }

    private DateTimeFormatConstant findDateTimeFormat(String timestamp) {
        DateTimeFormatConstant currentFormat = null;
        for (DateTimeFormatConstant format : DateTimeFormatConstant.values()) {
            boolean isValidFormat = validateFormat(format.value(), timestamp);
            if (isValidFormat) {
                currentFormat = format;
                break;
            }
        }
        return currentFormat;
    }

    private boolean validateFormat(String format, String time) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format);
        boolean isValid;
        try {
            try {
                LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(time, formatter);
                localDateTime.format(formatter);
                isValid = true;

            } catch (DateTimeException e) {
                ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(time, formatter);
                zonedDateTime.format(formatter);
                isValid = true;
            }
        } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
            isValid = false;
        }
        return isValid;
    }

    private LocalDateTime zonedTimeWithOffsetToUtc(String time, String format) {
        ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(time, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format));
        ZonedDateTime utcTime = zonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);

        return utcTime.toLocalDateTime();
    }


    private LocalDateTime localTimeToUtc(String time, String format) {

        AuthenticationDetails authDetails = (AuthenticationDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getDetails();
        ZoneId zoneId = authDetails.getZoneId();

        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(time, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format));
        Instant instant = localDateTime.atZone(zoneId).toInstant();
        ZonedDateTime zonedDateTimeUTC = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC"));

        return zonedDateTimeUTC.toLocalDateTime();
    }
}
```

I want to add a new case to this method whereby the user provides a time zone offset in the request headers. I'm not sure how I can pass a header from my controller to the custom deserializer. Any thoughts?

So far, I've looked into using ThreadLocal but I fear that may be dangerous in the future when multiple requests are being processed on the same thread.